# VS2008 javascript debugger in usercontrol

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging

In a VS2008 web project I have a usercontrol with some javascript that I want to debug. When I try to set a breakpoint I get "This is not a valid location for a breakpoint". I tried this on a regular aspx page and was able to set the breakpoint just fine.

Is there some limitation for setting javascript breakpoints in usercontrols? Is there some setting that needs to change?

Thanks

Comment: After much googling and research I have found that this DOES SEEM TO BE AN ISSUE WITH USER CONTROLS. MS - are you listening? Is there a reason you have disabled javascript debugging breakpoints in user controls ??? I mean we can still debug by adding the debugger; in the code - so why not just let us set the breakpoint ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to set a break point in my usercontrol either.

You can try adding the `debugger;` keyword, `Sys.Debug.fail('message')` or `Sys.Debugger.assert(a == 1)` to your javascript to force a breakpoint to work around this issue.

Comment: Yes - you could actually even do that in VS2005 - just want to get the product to work as advertised. I guess since it only seems to be an issuue when in a user control I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

in vs.net you can add keyword debugger in your js function ,with the help of browser development piug-in ,as firebug(firefox,ie also has a dev plug-in like this) ,the page will stop at the line where you declure debugger.
eg:

```
<script>
function myFunc()
{
  debugger;
  //do sth

}
</script>
```